# Resource ID nvarchar(MAX)

Tags: php, sql, nvarchar

I can't seem to get a straight answer on this.

I am fetching the contents of a field which is of type nvarchar(MAX) in the SQLSRV database however I keep getting "Resource id #1" when I echo the result of a field returned from a query instead of the contents. I am fairly new to SQLSRV and PHP but from what I understand is this value a pointer to somewhere else where the actually contents I need is?

If so how do I get to this data.

I have tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $stmt= sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC));

$getNext = sqlsrv_fetch($stmt);
$result = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 1); // this is the nvarchar(max) field

echo $result; // this shows Resource id #1;

// I tried
//$resource = sqlsrv_fetch($result); // this creates errors
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

NVARCHAR(MAX) will handle storage concerns for you, storing anything less approx 4000 chars in the table but anything greater in a separate location with a pointer in the table. The good news is that SQL Server presents the data returned back to you as if it was stored in the table so the usage of NVARCHAR(MAX) shouldn't be the cause of your problem, it just works like a normal table field.

Just found this, may help...

```
/*Get the second field of the row as a stream.
Because the default return type for a nvarchar field is a
string, the return type must be specified as a stream. */
$stream = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 1, 
                            SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM( SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR));
while( !feof( $stream))
{ 
    $str = fread( $stream, 10000);
    echo $str;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296207(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: So how do I get the contents instead of "Resource id #1"?

Comment: Are you sure that the nvarchar(max) field is index 1? the sqlsrv_get_field is zero based.

Comment: that's what is being shown when I echo the contents of that field.